# getting colons after every description item (not using listing package)

Tags: description

current output:

**Desc 1** Bla 1

wanted output:

**Desc 1:** Bla 1

---

MWEs:

current output:

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{german}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
\begin{description}
\item[Desc 1] Bla 1
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

wanted output:

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{german}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
\begin{description}
\item[Desc 1:] Bla 1
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

of course I know I could do it by regex replace... but i'm pretty sure there is an easier and more elegant way. and also i'm looking for a solution for the case where i have >100 items

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redefine `\descriptionlabel` to add the colon:

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{german}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\renewcommand*{\descriptionlabel}[1]{\hspace{\labelsep}\descfont #1:}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}
\item[Desc 1] Bla 1
\item[Desc 2] Bla 2
\item[Desc 3] Bla 3
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

I didn't make any prevision in the case in which the optional argument of `\item` isn't used, since this wouldn't make sense in the first place in a `description`.

Comment: What's the conditional for? Using `\item` alone inside `description` is wrong anyway.

Comment: @egre You're right. I've suppressed the conditional.

Answer (score 0):

This redefines `\item`, but will give default behavior (omit the colon) when no optional argument is specified.

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{scrartcl}
%\usepackage{polyglossia}
%\setdefaultlanguage{german}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
\let\svitem\item
\renewcommand\item[1][\relax]{\ifx\relax#1\svitem\else\svitem[#1:]\fi}
\begin{document}
\begin{description}
\item[Desc 1] Bla 1
\item Default empty tag
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Because it redefines `\item`, the above MWE will affect other list types.  However, that can be avoided with the following MWE, which will only affect the `description` environment.

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{scrartcl}
%\usepackage{polyglossia}
%\setdefaultlanguage{german}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
\let\svitem\item
\newcommand\altitem[1][\relax]{\ifx\relax#1\svitem\else\svitem[#1:]\fi}
\let\svdescription\description
\def\description{\let\item\altitem\svdescription}
\begin{document}
\begin{description}
\item[Desc 1] Bla 1
\item Default empty tag
\end{description}
\begin{itemize}
\item[Desc 1] Bla 1
\item Default empty tag
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```